# Can “spooky” and “sketchy” be considered synonyms?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, slang

German kids widely use a mixture of German and English (Denglish). I'm a German boomer, and strongly dislike my daughter's (24) usage of Denglish. Normally she simply uses correctly translated English words mixed into German sentences.

Yesterday she told me about some guy with whom she's acquainted (about her age) who's also an insurance agent. He tried to sell her insurance, she was pondering the offer when she found out that the guy had the same surname as one of the presidents of the insurance company. She said in German "Das fand ich sketchy". I asked what she wanted to express with "sketchy", and she explained a feeling of uneasiness. There are many words she could have used in German, like "seltsam", "fischig", "komisch" and so on. None of these words translates to "sketchy", a short proper translation would be "spooky". When I pointed this out, she claimed that "sketchy" and "spooky" can be used as synonyms by modern American youth, with "sketchy" being somewhat less threatening. Is she right?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149651/discussion-on-question-by-batox-can-spooky-and-sketchy-be-considered-synonym); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Did you look them up? e.g. Google says: **spooky**: *"... weird; eerie"* ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spooky)); **sketchy**: *"dishonest or disreputable."*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sketchy* means [in this respect] dishonest or disreputable, rather than its usual 'not highly detailed'.

Spooky doesn't really cover it in either usage, 'scary' or 'easily scared', but 'fishy' [fischig] does.

If something doesn't quite feel true or honest, it smells fishy.

Even in the notoriously unreliable & random Urban Dictionary I couldn't find anything that would let me equate sketchy with spooky.

Playing fast and loose with Google Translate, to remain colloquial, the British equivalent of the US 'sketchy' might be 'dodgy', which google translates to *zwielichtig*, which then translates back to 'shady', which is close.

*From my built-in Apple dictionary…

> **sketchy | ˈskɛtʃi |**
>
> adjective (sketchier, sketchiest)
>
> 1. not thorough or detailed: *the information they had was sketchy*.
>    • (of a picture) resembling a sketch; consisting of outline without much
>    detail: *a sketchy pencil drawing by Toulouse-Lautrec*.
> 2. *North American informal* - dishonest or disreputable: *once the story does come out, the fact that you tried to hide it will seem
>    sketchy | a sketchy neighbourhood.*

Comment: Yeah, sketchy is generally applied to people, meaning dishonest or suspicious; while spooky would normally be used of places, buildings, etc, which have an atmosphere of something ghostly or supernaturally dangerous. I have heard "spooky" used insultingly of people who dress in black and are generally gothy (e.g. "spooky bitch"), but in that case it doesn't mean dishonest or suspicious, just different.

Comment: Yes, Urban Dictionary has several mentions of it being 'cool' for goths etc. I didn't include it here, as it didn't seem relevant.

Comment: I would have thought *sketchy* was closer to *dubious* in English, so words like *fragwürdig* in German

Comment: @StuartF 'Sketchy' is also used w/ regard to things and places e.g. "a sketchy website" or "sketchy wiring".  A building might be called 'sketchy' if it appears structurally unsound or, a house might be 'sketchy' if there are people coming and going at all hours of the day.

Comment: To me the key is as @StuartF mentions: 'suspicious'.  If you know there's something wrong, it's not sketchy, it's just a scam or otherwise bad.  'Sketchy' implies that you don't really know for sure.

Comment: I agree with BrEnglish "sketchy" being close to dubious or dodgy, especially in this context. In other contexts it could mean risky or dangerous - "I had to drive home through that snowstorm last week and it was pretty sketchy at times"

Comment: @AdamV To clarify: I think you mean that the American English word ‘sketchy’ means close to the British English words ‘dodgy’ and ‘dubious’.  (At least, that's what I _hope_ you mean, coz it's the only way that makes sense to me :-)  And your last quote must be using the American English meaning of ‘sketchy’.

Comment: Can you add some support (a linked attributed reference) for the claim in the first sentence, Tetsujin, together with a caveat about register (is it recent slang, for instance)?

Comment: '[North American] [informal]' is exactly what's required. Thank you.

Comment: @Tetsujin as another Brit I do use it pretty naturally, and don't consciously perceive it as an Americanism. I do definitely associate it much more with younger speakers than older (who'd be more likely to use words like "dodgy") though, which is what we'd expect for an Americanism

Comment: @Tristan - if forced into a distinction, I might say it's in my lexicon, but not in my vocabulary - if that makes sense. I'm not 'young'.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah that makes sense. What I'd say is that it's in your passive vocabulary (what you readily understand), but not your active vocabulary (what you readily use). Ftr I'm 29 so my speech has quite a lot of Americanisms (although fewer than many of my peers)

Comment: @gidds I can't comment on American English, only British English as I hear it around me from younger colleagues or my kids. I hear British English speakers using "sketchy" to mean dubious, dodgy, risky or dangerous (context dependant). Whether they have picked up an American usage I can't really say.  Usage is usage, and they use it.

Answer (score 6):

These words as used are from two different subcultural usages.

*sketchy* [comes from](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sketchy) the concept of a plan not being explained to the speaker completely. The speaker implicitly assumes that because they do not know the details, they are somehow fraudulent, unethical or otherwise wrong. The link provided (M-W) seems to show that this word has been pushed forward to mean *questionable.* This has been a very common word in American English vernacular, and it is (or was) often shortened to *sketch.* Lately other words, especially *sus* (for *suspect*) seem to have replaced this to a large degree.

*spooky* originally [meant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spooky) more literally frightening from a less conscious sense; think horror movies. The usage in this context is more common in non-American English vernacular. I am a native American English speaker so I can't comment on how it has weathered the dawn of TikTok.

Answer (score 5):

You've both got a point.

Both something *spooky*, and something *sketchy* can provoke uneasiness.  But they're not synonyms, and it's a different sort of uneasiness.  The former is the spine-tingling uneasiness of a haunted house or a not-too-shocking horror movie. The latter is more the feeling that you might be about to be ripped off, robbed, or suffer some other realistic loss or harm.

My German is rather rusty,  but I'd say that *komisch* in particular isn't a great match to either, but closer to *sketchy* as it's the right sort of strangeness.

To me, and admittedly this is from a British perspective, *spooky* doesn't work here (neither does *creepy* which is a synonym when talking about a place, but not about a person).  *Sketchy* and *dodgy* both describe a suspicious deal quite well.

Answer (score 4):

Tetsujin's answer is correct, but it occurs to me that perhaps your daughter was thinking of the term 'spooked' when she said 'spooky'.  It's completely understandable that these terms could be confused because they are related but the meanings are distinct.

[**spook**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spooked) (verb):

> to make frightened or frantic : SCARE
> especially : to startle into violent activity (such as stampeding)

In this context, she was 'spooked' when she found this information.  You might encounter this usage in crime dramas where e.g. someone says the target of an undercover investigation was 'spooked' by an overly aggressive attempt to catch them in an illegal act, causing that target to become suspicious.

It makes logical sense that someone who 'spooked' you would be called 'spooky', but isn't typically how these words are used in relation to each other.  I can imagine that in a punny kind of way, though.

... And when I checked [spooky](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spooky), it seems that spooky can have a related usage, but it's for the person/thing that is spooked, as opposed to the person/thing doing the spooking.  An example (2) given there is:

> Dealing with Louisa when she was having an attack was very much like dealing with a spooky horse.

In this case, they mean a horse that is easily spooked. That usage is not familiar to my ear, however.